# How can I write nested for loops recursively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have the following code for processing an XML file:

```
for el in root:
    checkChild(rootDict, el)
    for child in el:
        checkChild(rootDict, el, child)
        for grandchild in child:
            checkChild(rootDict, el, child, grandchild)
            for grandgrandchild in grandchild:
                checkChild(rootDict, el, child, grandchild, grandgrandchild)
                ...
                   ...
```

As you can see, on every iteration I just call the same function with one extra parameter. Is there a way to avoid writing so many nested for loops that basically do the same thing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511586/nested-loop-recursion

Comment: What does `checkChild` return? A boolean?

Comment: What kind of object is root? Does it comes from ElementTree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever operation you wish to perform on files and directories you can traverse them. In python the easiest way I know is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

# Set the directory you want to start from
root_dir = '.'
for dir_name, subdirList, file_list in os.walk(root_dir):
    print(f'Found directory: {dir_name}s')
    for file_name in file_list:
        print(f'\t{file_name}s')
```

while traversing you can add the to groups or perform other operations

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `root` comes from an ElemenTree parsing, you can make a datastructure containing the list of all the ancestors for each node, cnd then iterate over this to call checkChild:

```
def checkChild(*element_chain):
    # Code placeholder
    print("Checking %s" % '.'.join(t.tag for t in reversed(element_chain)))

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
# Build a dict containing each node and its ancestors
nodes_and_parents = {}
for elem in tree.iter():  # tree.iter yields every tag in the XML, not only the root childs 
    for child in elem:
        nodes_and_parents[child] = [elem, ] + nodes_and_parents.get(elem, [])

for t, parents in nodes_and_parents.items():
    checkChild(t, *parents)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def recurse(tree):
    """Walks a tree depth-first and yields the path at every step."""
    # We convert the tree to a list of paths through it,
    # with the most recently visited path last. This is the stack.
    def explore(stack):
        try:
            # Popping from the stack means reading the most recently
            # discovered but yet unexplored path in the tree. We yield it
            # so you can call your method on it.
            path = stack.pop()
        except IndexError:
            # The stack is empty. We're done.
            return
        yield path
        # Then we expand this path further, adding all extended paths to the
        # stack. In reversed order so the first child element will end up at
        # the end, and thus will be yielded first.
        stack.extend(path + (elm,) for elm in reversed(path[-1]))
    yield from explore([(tree,)])

# The linear structure yields tuples (root, child, ...)
linear = recurse(root)

# Then call checkChild(rootDict, child, ...)
next(linear)  # skip checkChild(rootDict)
for path in linear:
    checkChild(rootDict, *path[1:])
```

For your understanding, suppose the root looked something like this:

```
root
  child1
    sub1
    sub2
  child2
    sub3
      subsub1
    sub4
  child3
```

That is like a tree. We can find a few paths through this tree, e.g. `(root, child1)`. And as you feed these paths to `checkChild` this would result in a call `checkChild(rootNode, child1)`. Eventually `checkChild` will be called exactly once for every path in the tree. We can thus write the tree as a list of paths like so:

```
[(root,),
 (root, child1),
 (root, child1, sub1),
 (root, child1, sub2),
 (root, child2),
 (root, child2, sub3),
 (root, child2, sub3, subsub1),
 (root, child2, sub4),
 (root, child3)]
```

The *order* of paths in this list happens to match your loop structure. It is called **depth-first**. (Another sort order, *breadth-first*, would first list all child nodes, then all sub nodes and finally all subsub nodes.)

The list above is the same as the `stack` variable in the code, with a small change that `stack` only stores the minimal number of paths it needs to remember.

To conclude, `recurse` yields those paths one-by-one and the last bit of code invokes the `checkChild` method as you do in your question.